# What is a good XML stream parser for Python?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, stream

Are there any XML parsers for Python that can parse file streams? My XML files are too big to fit in memory, so I need to parse the stream.

Ideally I wouldn't have to have root access to install things, so `lxml` is not a very good option.

I have been using `xml.etree.ElementTree` but [I am convinced it is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693515/what-is-wrong-with-this-code-using-elementtree).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `xml.etree.cElementTree`. It's much faster than `xml.etree.ElementTree`. Neither of them are broken. Your files are broken (see my answer to your other question).

Comment: Indeed, it is much faster. And yes, my files were broken.

Comment: Guy was asking about streaming parser.

Comment: @mcepl: Guy wanted to parse huge files; guy can do that with `iterparse()`. What/where is *your* answer?

Comment: Isn't iterparse() building the tree as well (“Note that iterparse still builds a tree, just like parser.” http://effbot.org/zone/element-iterparse.htm). And my answer was bumping the one by Peter Viktorin.

Comment: Just FYI: in 2019, `cElementTree` is simply an alias for `ElementTree`.

Comment: I second @Marco. [The xml.etree.cElementTree module is deprecated.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree)

Answer (score 22):

Here's [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9814580/2072035) about [`xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse) practice on huge XML files. `lxml` has the method as well. The key to stream parsing with `iterparse` is manual clearing and removing already processed nodes, because otherwise you will end up running out of memory.

Another option is using [`xml.sax`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.sax.html). The official manual is too formal to me, and lacks examples so it needs clarification along with the question. Default parser module, `xml.sax.expatreader`, implement incremental parsing interface `xml.sax.xmlreader.IncrementalParser`. That is to say `xml.sax.make_parser()` provides suitable stream parser.

For instance, given a XML stream like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <entry><a>value 0</a><b foo='bar' /></entry>
  <entry><a>value 1</a><b foo='baz' /></entry>
  <entry><a>value 2</a><b foo='quz' /></entry>
  ...
</root>
```

Can be handled in the following way.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import xml.sax


class StreamHandler(xml.sax.handler.ContentHandler):

  lastEntry = None
  lastName  = None


  def startElement(self, name, attrs):
    self.lastName = name
    if name == 'entry':
      self.lastEntry = {}
    elif name != 'root':
      self.lastEntry[name] = {'attrs': attrs, 'content': ''}

  def endElement(self, name):
    if name == 'entry':
      print({
        'a' : self.lastEntry['a']['content'],
        'b' : self.lastEntry['b']['attrs'].getValue('foo')
      })
      self.lastEntry = None
    elif name == 'root':
      raise StopIteration

  def characters(self, content):
    if self.lastEntry:
      self.lastEntry[self.lastName]['content'] += content


if __name__ == '__main__':
  # use default ``xml.sax.expatreader``
  parser = xml.sax.make_parser()
  parser.setContentHandler(StreamHandler())
  # feed the parser with small chunks to simulate
  with open('data.xml') as f:
    while True:
      buffer = f.read(16)
      if buffer:
        try:
          parser.feed(buffer)
        except StopIteration:
          break
  # if you can provide a file-like object it's as simple as
  with open('data.xml') as f:
    parser.parse(f)
```

Comment: Thank you Saaj. I have finally found an answer to my own question thanks to you answer. See my more elaborate answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44398623/938111

Comment: Dumb question but what is the `time.sleep(2)` for?

Comment: @gman It's a good question in fact. It's hard to remember what was the intention behind `else` branch. Probably related to experimenting with simulating slow input. But I copy-pasted the snippet and ran it with `raise RuntimeError` in place of `time.sleep` call. It ran successfully, so it's a dead branch. Removed it.

Answer (score 12):

Are you looking for [`xml.sax`](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.sax.html)? It's right in the standard library.