# Extract data from 2.8 GB XML file and save it to CSV/Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, xml, csv, elementtree

**File Link:** https://bulkdata.uspto.gov/data/trademark/dailyxml/assignments/asb19550103-20211231-01.zip

I needed to search for some data inside this file, but I can't read this file directly into the python program because of large size.

I have tried extracting the data from this XML file using various methods, but it seems that it doesn't have the proper XML format or some other issue. Also, I don't exactly about the columns inside this file because I can open it. I am adding all the codes that I had tried.

```
     import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
     import pandas as pd

     xml_data = open("/content/apc220822.xml", 'r').read()  # Read file
     root = ET.XML(xml_data)  # Parse XML

     data = []
     cols = []
     for i, child in enumerate(root):
         data.append([subchild.text for subchild in child])
         cols.append(child.tag)

     df = pd.DataFrame(data).T  # Write in DF and transpose it
     df.columns = cols  # Update column names
     print(df)

     df = pd.DataFrame(data).T  # Write in DF and transpose it
     df.columns = cols  # Update column names
     print(df)
```

**Required Solution:**
I want to extract data from this XML and save it to Pandas DataFrame/CSV format so I can search the data using python from it.
I do have 64GB RAM available. So just suggest to me any other method like saving this XML file data to a database etc, from where I can read it directly into the python program and find required data inside of it.

Comment: Have you studied [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809469/python-sax-to-lxml-for-80gb-xml/9814580#9814580) ?

Comment: Yes I had, And tried them as well

Answer (score 0):

In this answer I am going to use the [`bixml`](https://bigxml.rogdham.net/) library for parsing big XML files.

*Disclaimer: I am the author of this library.*

I don't know about `panda` nor what you are trying to do exactly, but since you mentioned CSV and searching are what you want to do, I show example of how to get some data in a pythonic way out of the XML file, which should be a good starting point to using that data however you want.

---

For future reference, here is what the XML file looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- redacted -->
<trademark-assignments>
    <!-- redacted -->
    <assignment-information>
        <assignment-entry>
            <assignment>
                <reel-no>1</reel-no>
                <frame-no>0001</frame-no>
                <last-update-date>19910716</last-update-date>
                <purge-indicator>N</purge-indicator>
                <date-recorded>19550103</date-recorded>
                <page-count>0</page-count>
                <correspondent>
                    <person-or-organization-name/>
                </correspondent>
                <conveyance-text>CHANGE OF NAME 19530513</conveyance-text>
            </assignment>
            <assignors>
                <assignor>
                    <person-or-organization-name>HAWK AND BUCK COMPANY, INC., THE</person-or-organization-name>
                    <city>DALLAS</city>
                    <state>TEXAS</state>
                    <execution-date>19530513</execution-date>
                    <legal-entity-text>UNKNOWN</legal-entity-text>
                </assignor>
            </assignors>
            <assignees>
                <assignee>
                    <person-or-organization-name>GRIFFIN, C. C., MANUFACTURING COMPANY</person-or-organization-name>
                    <city>FORT WORTH</city>
                    <state>TEXAS</state>
                    <legal-entity-text>UNKNOWN</legal-entity-text>
                </assignee>
            </assignees>
            <properties>
                <property>
                    <serial-no>71231446</serial-no>
                    <registration-no>218184</registration-no>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <serial-no>71538408</serial-no>
                    <registration-no>506247</registration-no>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <serial-no>71510081</serial-no>
                    <registration-no>509215</registration-no>
                </property>
            </properties>
        </assignment-entry>
        <!-- redacted -->
    </assignment-information>
</trademark-assignments>
```

---

Let's say you are interested into getting for each *assignment entry* the *city* and *state* of the *assignor*, as well as all *properties* (*serial-no* & *registration-no*).

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from pprint import pprint
from typing import List, Optional
from zipfile import ZipFile

from bigxml import Parser, xml_handle_element


@xml_handle_element("assignor")
@dataclass
class Assignor:
    city: str = "N/A"
    state: str = "N/A"

    @xml_handle_element("city")
    def handle_city(self, node):
        self.city = node.text

    @xml_handle_element("state")
    def handle_state(self, node):
        self.state = node.text


@xml_handle_element("property")
@dataclass
class Property:
    serial: Optional[int] = None
    registration: Optional[int] = None

    @xml_handle_element("serial-no")
    def handle_serial(self, node):
        self.serial = int(node.text)

    @xml_handle_element("registration-no")
    def handle_registration(self, node):
        self.registration = int(node.text)


@xml_handle_element("trademark-assignments", "assignment-information", "assignment-entry")
@dataclass
class AssignmentEntry:
    assignor: Optional[Assignor] = None
    properties: List[Property] = field(default_factory=list)

    @xml_handle_element("assignors")
    def handle_assignors(self, node):
        self.assignor = node.return_from(Assignor)

    @xml_handle_element("properties")
    def handle_properties(self, node):
        self.properties.extend(node.iter_from(Property))


with ZipFile("asb19550103-20211231-01.zip") as zip_file:
    with zip_file.open("asb19550103-20211231-01.xml") as xml_file:
        for assignment_entry in Parser(xml_file).iter_from(AssignmentEntry):
            pprint(assignment_entry)
            # do whatever you want with assignment_entry here
```

Running the above code will output all `AssignmentEntry` instances:

```py
AssignmentEntry(assignor=Assignor(city='DALLAS', state='TEXAS'),
                properties=[Property(serial=71231446, registration=218184),
                            Property(serial=71538408, registration=506247),
                            Property(serial=71510081, registration=509215)])
AssignmentEntry(assignor=Assignor(city='JERSEY CITY', state='NEW JERSEY'),
                properties=[Property(serial=71230951, registration=217985),
                            Property(serial=71224781, registration=212380),
                            Property(serial=71255202, registration=243916),
                            Property(serial=71486386, registration=420259),
                            Property(serial=71515236, registration=434974),
                            Property(serial=71620823, registration=572309)])
AssignmentEntry(assignor=Assignor(city='SANTA BARBARA', state='CALIFORNIA'),
                properties=[Property(serial=71564699, registration=542581),
                            Property(serial=71564406, registration=578399)])
... etc. ...
```

I chose to use [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) to hold the data, but feel free to use other data representation.

For more information on the usage of the `bigxml` library, please refer to [its documentation](https://bigxml.rogdham.net/).