# Parsing incrementally a large wikipedia dump XML file using python

Tags: python, xml, xml-namespaces, wikipedia, iterparse

The goal is to read all … stuff from a Wikipedia DUMP (70Gb file). This is not possible to load in memory, therefore I tried to parse the file incrementally and get some values from it. However the script I just wrote does not print anything and immediately occupies all my memory.

Here is the code:

```
from lxml import etree

def fast_iter(context, func, *args, **kwargs):

    for event, elem in context:
        func(elem, *args, **kwargs)

        elem.clear()

        for ancestor in elem.xpath('ancestor-or-self::*'):
            while ancestor.getprevious() is not None:
                del ancestor.getparent()[0]
    del context


def process_element(elem):
    #print(elem)
    print (elem.xpath( './revision/text/text( )' ))

context = etree.iterparse( 'enwiki-latest-pages-articles-multistream.xml', tag='page' )
fast_iter(context,process_element)
```

When this script is applied in a small xml file, it prints the values from the requested xpath.

However when applied on the full file, nothing happens.

Here are a same lines from the Wikipedia dump

```
<mediawiki xmlns="http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10/ http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10.xsd" version="0.10" xml:lang="en">
  <siteinfo>
    <sitename>Wikipedia</sitename>
    <dbname>enwiki</dbname>
    <base>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page</base>
    <generator>MediaWiki 1.33.0-wmf.19</generator>
    <case>first-letter</case>
    <namespaces>
      <namespace key="-2" case="first-letter">Media</namespace>
      <namespace key="-1" case="first-letter">Special</namespace>
      <namespace key="0" case="first-letter" />
      <namespace key="1" case="first-letter">Talk</namespace>
      <namespace key="2" case="first-letter">User</namespace>
      <namespace key="3" case="first-letter">User talk</namespace>
      <namespace key="4" case="first-letter">Wikipedia</namespace>
      <namespace key="5" case="first-letter">Wikipedia talk</namespace>
      <namespace key="6" case="first-letter">File</namespace>
      <namespace key="7" case="first-letter">File talk</namespace>
      <namespace key="8" case="first-letter">MediaWiki</namespace>
      <namespace key="9" case="first-letter">MediaWiki talk</namespace>
      <namespace key="10" case="first-letter">Template</namespace>
      <namespace key="11" case="first-letter">Template talk</namespace>
      <namespace key="12" case="first-letter">Help</namespace>
      <namespace key="13" case="first-letter">Help talk</namespace>
      <namespace key="14" case="first-letter">Category</namespace>
      <namespace key="15" case="first-letter">Category talk</namespace>
      <namespace key="100" case="first-letter">Portal</namespace>
      <namespace key="101" case="first-letter">Portal talk</namespace>
      <namespace key="108" case="first-letter">Book</namespace>
      <namespace key="109" case="first-letter">Book talk</namespace>
      <namespace key="118" case="first-letter">Draft</namespace>
      <namespace key="119" case="first-letter">Draft talk</namespace>
      <namespace key="446" case="first-letter">Education Program</namespace>
      <namespace key="447" case="first-letter">Education Program talk</namespace>
      <namespace key="710" case="first-letter">TimedText</namespace>
      <namespace key="711" case="first-letter">TimedText talk</namespace>
      <namespace key="828" case="first-letter">Module</namespace>
      <namespace key="829" case="first-letter">Module talk</namespace>
      <namespace key="2300" case="first-letter">Gadget</namespace>
      <namespace key="2301" case="first-letter">Gadget talk</namespace>
      <namespace key="2302" case="case-sensitive">Gadget definition</namespace>
      <namespace key="2303" case="case-sensitive">Gadget definition talk</namespace>
    </namespaces>
  </siteinfo>
  <page>
    <title>AccessibleComputing</title>
    <ns>0</ns>
    <id>10</id>
    <redirect title="Computer accessibility" />
    <revision>
      <id>854851586</id>
      <parentid>834079434</parentid>
      <timestamp>2018-08-14T06:47:24Z</timestamp>
      <contributor>
        <username>Godsy</username>
        <id>23257138</id>
      </contributor>
      <comment>remove from category for seeking instructions on rcats</comment>
      <model>wikitext</model>
      <format>text/x-wiki</format>
      <text xml:space="preserve">#REDIRECT [[Computer accessibility]]

{{R from move}}
{{R from CamelCase}}
{{R unprintworthy}}</text>
      <sha1>42l0cvblwtb4nnupxm6wo000d27t6kf</sha1>
    </revision>
  </page>
  <page>
    <title>Anarchism</title>
    <ns>0</ns>
    <id>12</id>
    <revision>
      <id>885648527</id>
      <parentid>885645378</parentid>
      <timestamp>2019-03-01T11:16:23Z</timestamp>
      <contributor>
        <username>Jarnsax</username>
        <id>33627956</id>
      </contributor>
      <comment>improve citation metadata</comment>
      <model>wikitext</model>
      <format>text/x-wiki</format>
      <text xml:space="preserve">{{redirect2|Anarchist|Anarchists|the fictional character|Anarchist (comics)|other uses|Anarchists (disambiguation)}}
{{pp-move-indef}}
{{short description|Political philosophy that advocates self-governed societies}}
{{Use dmy dates|date=July 2018}}
{{use British English|date=January 2014}}
{{Anarchism sidebar}}
{{Basic forms of government}}
'''Anarchism''' is an [[anti-authoritarian]] [[political philosophy]]{{sfn|McLaughlin|2007|p=59}}{{sfn|Flint|2009|p=27}} that advocates [[Self-governance|self-governed]] societies based on voluntary, [[cooperative]] institutions and the rejection of coercive [[Hierarchy|hierarchies]] those societies view as unjust. These institutions are often described as [[Stateless society|stateless societies]],{{r|group=note|Note01}}{{sfn|Sheehan|2003|p=85}} although several authors have defined them more specifically as distinct institutions based on non-hierarchical or [[Free association (communism and anarchism)|free associations]].{{r|group=note|Note02}} Anarchism holds the [[State (polity)|state]] to be undesirable, unnecessary, and harmful.{{r|group=note|Note03}}&lt;ref name=definition /&gt; Any philosophy consistent with statelessness, that is, principled opposition to the State, is anarchist, thus anarchist schools of thought range from [[anarcho-communism]] to [[anarcho-capitalism]].{{sfn|Fiala|2018}}

While [[Anti-statism|opposition to the state]] is central,{{r|group=note|Note04}} many forms of anarchism specifically entail opposing authority or hierarchical organisation based on authority in the conduct of all human relations.{{r|group=note|Note05}} Anarchism is often considered a [[Far-left politics|far-left]] ideology,{{r|group=note|Note06}}{{sfn|Kahn|2000}}{{sfn|Moyihan|2007}} and much of [[anarchist economics]] and [[Anarchist law|anarchist legal philosophy]] reflect [[Libertarian socialism|anti-authoritarian interpretations]] of [[Anarcho-communism|communism]], [[Collectivist anarchism|collectivism]], [[Anarcho-syndicalism|syndicalism]], [[Mutualism (economic theory)|mutualism]], or [[participatory economics]].{{r|group=note|Note07}}

Anarchism does not offer a fixed body of doctrine from a single particular world view, instead fluxing and flowing as a philosophy.{{sfn|Marshall|2010|p=16}} Many types and traditions of anarchism exist, not all of which are mutually exclusive.{{sfn|Sylvan|2007|p=262}} [[Anarchist schools of thought]] can differ fundamentally, supporting anything from extreme [[individualism]] to complete [[collectivism]].{{sfn|McLean|McMillan|2003|loc= Anarchism}} Strains of anarchism have often been divided into the categories of [[Social anarchism|social]] and [[individualist anarchism]] or similar dual classifications.{{sfn|Ostergaard|p=14|loc=Anarchism}}{{sfn|Kropotkin|2002|p=5}}{{sfn|Fowler|1972}}
   </text>
   </revision>
   </page>
</mediawiki>
```

Has anybody did this before? Any idea how to efficient parse this huge dump? Is there any package/lib that has done it before? I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Why is `elem.clear()` there? That will remove all subelements so subsequent attempts to find elements below `elem` will not return anything.

Comment: Wht output *do* you get? Absolutely nothing? How long might your code take to read 70gigabytes - have you waited long enough?

Comment: @barny I am not taking output, I waited for about 5 minutes. However I would expect that since we are iterating every 'page' element, output should have been instantly produced. Or my assumption is wrong?

Comment: You could try a [SAX parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693535/what-is-a-good-xml-stream-parser-for-python#22504625) instead, which is natively designed for streaming.

Comment: If you look at resource monitor while it's running, is disk I/O high as the file is still being reador has it dropped down (i.e. finished)? Have you tried making iterparse print something (a "."?) on a start event?

Comment: And what IS that elem.clear() doing?

Comment: To free up memory you MUST do `del elem` at the end of the for loop

Comment: @banny I removed the elem.clear() and add a del elem at the end of the loop. The disk I/O is 100% and after a couple of minutes the program crashes

Comment: *"And what IS that elem.clear() doing?"* This removes **all** children `Element` from a `Element`. This is used to **not** build a XML-Tree while parsing.

Comment: Yes I know - and where it is positioned in the code renders subsequent xpath statements pointless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Question**: Parsing incrementally a large wikipedia dump XML file
>   When this (*the Questions*) script is applied in a small xml file, it prints the values from the requested xpath.
>   However when applied on the full file, nothing happens.

I wonder, you get anything from the *small file*, as you don't use a `namespace` parameter.
The `Wikipedia` xml file uses the following default `namespace`:

```
<mediawiki xmlns="http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10/"
```

---

This example is using `lxml`:

```
from lxml import etree

class Wikipedia:
    def __init__(self, fh, tag):
        """
        Initialize 'iterparse' to only generate 'end' events on tag '<entity>'

        :param fh: File Handle from the XML File to parse
        :param tag: The tag to process
        """
        # Prepend the default Namespace {*} to get anything.
        self.context = etree.iterparse(fh, events=("end",), tag=['{*}' + tag])

    def _parse(self):
        """
        Parse the XML File for all '<tag>...</tag>' Elements
        Clear/Delete the Element Tree after processing

        :return: Yield the current 'Event, Element Tree'
        """
        for event, elem in self.context:
            yield event, elem

            elem.clear()
            while elem.getprevious() is not None:
                del elem.getparent()[0]

    def __iter__(self):
        """
        Iterate all '<tag>...</tag>' Element Trees yielded from self._parse()

        :return: Dict var 'entity' {tag1, value, tag2, value, ... ,tagn, value}}
        """
        for event, elem in self._parse():
            entity = {}

            # Assign the 'elem.namespace' to the 'xpath'
            entity['revision'] = elem.xpath('./xmlns:revision/xmlns:text/text( )', 
                                   namespaces={'xmlns':etree.QName(elem).namespace})

            yield entity


if __name__ == "__main__":
    XML = b""""""<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<mediawiki xmlns="http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10/ 
http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10.xsd"  
version="0.10" xml:lang="en">
  <siteinfo>
    <sitename>Wikipedia</sitename>
    <dbname>enwiki</dbname>
    ... (omitted for brevity)""""""

    #with open('.\\FILE.XML', 'rb') as in_xml_
    with io.BytesIO(XML) as in_xml:
        for record in Wikipedia(in_xml, tag='page'):
            print("record:{}".format(record))
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> record:{'revision': ['#REDIRECT [[Computer accessi... (omitted for brevity)
> record:{'revision': ["{{redirect2|Anarchist|Anarch... (omitted for brevity)
> ```

***Tested with Python: 3.5 - lxml.etree: 3.7.1***

Answer (score 1):

Use SAX. See example (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_xml_processing.htm)  below.

> Simple API for XML (SAX) − Here, you register callbacks for events of interest and then let the parser proceed through the document. **This is useful when your documents are large or you have memory limitations**, it parses the file as it reads it from the disk and the entire file is never stored in the memory.
>
> SAX is a standard interface for event-driven XML parsing. Parsing XML with SAX generally requires you to create your own ContentHandler by subclassing xml.sax.ContentHandler.

import xml.sax

```
class MovieHandler( xml.sax.ContentHandler ):
   def __init__(self):
      self.CurrentData = ""
      self.type = ""
      self.format = ""
      self.year = ""
      self.rating = ""
      self.stars = ""
      self.description = ""

   # Call when an element starts
   def startElement(self, tag, attributes):
      self.CurrentData = tag
      if tag == "movie":
         print ("*****Movie*****")
         title = attributes["title"]
         print ("Title:", title)

   # Call when an elements ends
   def endElement(self, tag):
      if self.CurrentData == "type":
         print ("Type:", self.type)
      elif self.CurrentData == "format":
         print ("Format:", self.format)
      elif self.CurrentData == "year":
         print ("Year:", self.year)
      elif self.CurrentData == "rating":
         print ("Rating:", self.rating)
      elif self.CurrentData == "stars":
         print ("Stars:", self.stars)
      elif self.CurrentData == "description":
         print ("Description:", self.description)
      self.CurrentData = ""

   # Call when a character is read
   def characters(self, content):
      if self.CurrentData == "type":
         self.type = content
      elif self.CurrentData == "format":
         self.format = content
      elif self.CurrentData == "year":
         self.year = content
      elif self.CurrentData == "rating":
         self.rating = content
      elif self.CurrentData == "stars":
         self.stars = content
      elif self.CurrentData == "description":
         self.description = content

if ( __name__ == "__main__"):

   # create an XMLReader
   parser = xml.sax.make_parser()
   # turn off namepsaces
   parser.setFeature(xml.sax.handler.feature_namespaces, 0)

   # override the default ContextHandler
   Handler = MovieHandler()
   parser.setContentHandler( Handler )

   parser.parse("c:\\temp\\movies.xml")
```

movies.xml

```
<collection shelf = "New Arrivals">
<movie title = "Enemy Behind">
   <type>War, Thriller</type>
   <format>DVD</format>
   <year>2003</year>
   <rating>PG</rating>
   <stars>10</stars>
   <description>Talk about a US-Japan war</description>
</movie>
<movie title = "Transformers">
   <type>Anime, Science Fiction</type>
   <format>DVD</format>
   <year>1989</year>
   <rating>R</rating>
   <stars>8</stars>
   <description>A schientific fiction</description>
</movie>
   <movie title = "Trigun">
   <type>Anime, Action</type>
   <format>DVD</format>
   <episodes>4</episodes>
   <rating>PG</rating>
   <stars>10</stars>
   <description>Vash the Stampede!</description>
</movie>
<movie title = "Ishtar">
   <type>Comedy</type>
   <format>VHS</format>
   <rating>PG</rating>
   <stars>2</stars>
   <description>Viewable boredom</description>
</movie>
</collection>
```